# Can't run encore dev

Tags: symfony, npm, webpack, webpack-encore

Why i have this erros when I want to use yarn run encore dev ? When I want to add sass i get warning " > sass-loader@6.0.7" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0". But why ? Symfony 4. I cant install from github this modules npm install --save child_process fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin fs module net readline spdx-exceptions spdx-license-ids spdx-license-ids/deprecated

## yarn run encore dev

yarn run v1.5.1
$ c:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\Symfony\pppp\node_modules.bin\encore dev
Running webpack ...

ERROR  Failed to compile with 50 errors                                                                        09:48:38

These dependencies were not found:

- child_process in ./node_modules/execa/index.js, ./node_modules/execa/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js and 1 other
- fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin in ./node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/lib/plugins/forked-ts-types.js
- fs in ./node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/lib/WebpackConfig.js, ./node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/lib/config/parse-runtime.js and 35 others
- module in (webpack)/lib/NormalModule.js, (webpack)/lib/node/NodeTargetPlugin.js
- net in ./node_modules/growly/lib/gntp.js, ./node_modules/node-notifier/lib/checkGrowl.js
- readline in ./node_modules/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/src/output.js
- spdx-exceptions in ./node_modules/spdx-expression-parse/scan.js
- spdx-license-ids in ./node_modules/spdx-correct/index.js, ./node_modules/spdx-expression-parse/scan.js
- spdx-license-ids/deprecated in ./node_modules/spdx-expression-parse/scan.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save child_process fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin fs module net readline spdx-exceptions spdx-license-ids spdx-license-ids/deprecated
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 2
Command: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
Arguments: /d /s /c c:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\Symfony\pppp\
ode_modules\.bin\encore dev
Directory: c:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\Symfony\pppp
Output:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "c:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\Symfony\swisscar\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: have you found a solution? I have the same issue and installing them doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have solved this issue by now but if not the solution to the problem lie in reading the error message. For starters the '*yarn run encore dev*' is complaining that some dependencies required by some of the libraries your application depend on, are missing from your installation of node.