# Command "encore" not found when trying yarn encore dev command

Tags: symfony, yarnpkg, package.json, webpack-encore

I am currently stuck at the Encore/Webpack installation. I followed the steps at [symfony.com](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#webpack-encore). But when continuing to [the simple example](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html) I got stuck at running `yarn encore dev`. I get the error: "Command "encore" not found". I also have an error when running `symfony server:start` after installing Encore and navigating to a view:

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Could not find the entrypoints file from Webpack: the file "path/entrypoints.json" does not exist.").`

As far as I know the entrypoints.json should have been autogenerated. I have Yarn 1.22.10 and NodeJS 14.16.1.

#### What I have done

I executed the commands `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle`
and `yarn install`

1. I looked at StackOveflow questions ['error Command "encore" not found.' when running 'yarn run encore' in Symfony4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56259798/4815184), [webpack encore dev-server not found /](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59453681/4815184), [Error Command "encore" not found. (separate backend webpack)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53302142/4815184), [Can't run encore dev](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49358898/4815184)
2. I executed the command `composer require webpack`
3. I noticed my package.json doesn't have a scripts object where the command `encore dev` is supposed to be living. I watched a YouTube video and followed it (https://youtu.be/Fs_4FMoSO90). That's why I know this. I wonder why I don't have it. Below is the package.json from the video. My package.json only has the dev dependency Bootstrap.
4. Executed `npm install`

Package.json from video:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.31.0",
    "core-js": "^3.0.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
    "dev": "encore dev",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch",
    "build": "encore production --progress"
  }
}
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

I removed the package.json, package-lock.json and executed `yarn install` again and it installed some packages. I didn't need NPM. I already got Bootstrap from my Yarn.lock (that's the only thing in there). I still have both errors though.

After Yivi's advice I executed `composer req webpack`, `yarn install` and `yarn encore dev`. The difference is that I executed `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` which is what is mentioned on the installation page on the symfony website. The `yarn encore dev` command tries to run webpack now, but I get the following error: `Error: Encore.enableStimulusBridge is not a recognized property or method. webpack.config.js:26 Object.<anonymous>`

webpack.config.js line 26

```
    // enables the Symfony UX Stimulus bridge (used in assets/bootstrap.js)
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')
```

Comment: Something else must be broken or you must be missing some step, despite you believing you are not. I just tried `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton test-encore`, `cd test-encore`, `composer req webpack`, `yarn install`, and `yarn encore dev` works perfectly.

Comment: I updated my question. I have NodeJS version 14.16.1. I accidentally gave my NPM version.

Comment: I executed ```composer req webpack```, ```yarn install``` and ```yarn encore dev```. The difference is that I executed ```composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle``` which is what is mentioned on the installation page on the symfony website. The ```yarn encore dev``` command tries to run webpack now, but I get the following error: ```Error: Encore.enableStimulusBridge is not a recognized property or method. webpack.config.js:26 Object.<anonymous>```.

Comment: Stimulus support was [added in 0.32](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/releases/tag/v0.32.0). Can you post the relevant sections fom _your_ files? You could also try [reinstalling the recipes](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-the-ux-initiative-a-new-javascript-ecosystem-for-symfony) and bumping your versions.

Comment: Upgrading stimulus and encore actually helped: https://symfony.com/blog/webpack-encore-1-0-and-stimulus-bridge-2-0-released

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your advice worked msg. I installed the recipes with `composer recipes:install symfony/webpack-encore-bundle --force -v` and now `yarn encore dev` compiles webpack successfully. I now also know that I accidentally kept the package.json from the video in my project which explains why my error changed from `Command encore not found` to `Error: Encore.enableStimulusBridge is not a recognized property or method. webpack.config.js:26 Object.<anonymous>`